# Python: Parsing math functions that are dependent on each other

Tags: python, parsing, math, sympy

I have a list of objects, each object is a mathematical function, and those functions may be dependent on each other, for example:

```py
[
 Formula("G", ["y"], "1 - y"),
 Formula("V", ["x", "y"], "G(y) * x / 3"),
 Formula("U", ["x", "y"],"(G(y)**2) / (9 * V(x, y)) + V(x, y)")
]
```

Where first argument is function name, second one is list of used variables, and third one is string - the function's expression.

Is there a simple way to evaluate value of function *U(x, y)* at a given point, for example, at [2, 3] and recursively call *G(3)* and *V(2, 3)*, and get the final result?

I have tried to do this in Sympy, but couldn't call for example function *G(y)* in function *V(x,y)*

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please show what you tried with sympy? Why couldn't you use G in V?

Comment: Would `x,y = sympy.symbols('x y'); G = 1-y; V = G * x / 3; U = G**2 / (9*V+V)` satisfy you? Also, note `9*V+V` can be simplified to `10*V`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Stef! I tried to call each function like a regular python function (like this `V = G(y) * x / 3`) and had an undesired output. Now, that you showed me how to call a function, I have just to format formulas expression and then eval() it. Although you really helped me and gave an Idea, I'm still wondering if I could do this without  formatting and eval()-ing it?

Comment: You might want to use sympy's `parse_expr` function.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @OscarBenjamin.
`F = parse_expr('1 + x', evaluate=True);
G = sp.Lambda(sp.symbols('x y'), parse_expr('F(x) + 3*y', evaluate=True));
G(2, 3)` would still return F(2) + 9, but not as I expect: 12. Could you clarify, how could I use `parse_expr`?

Comment: You'll need to pass a locals dict to `parse_expr` so it knows what `F` is.

Comment: Perhaps if you have fleshed out the solution you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions. In example I have given, the `Formula`s are in topological order, but in practice it will not always be so.

I could use @Stef's solution, but I would have to format the formula expressions and then `eval()` it

> x,y = sympy.symbols('x y'); G = 1-y; V = G * x / 3; U = G**2 / (9*V+V)

Then @OscarBenjamin suggested to use sympy's `parse_expr` which worked just fine, until I realized that formulas will not always be given in topological order. So I found out, that trying to put it in topological order and then parse it, would take too much execution time.

Eventually, I decided to make my own parser, which looks something like this (test classes and variables):

```py
import re
import copy

class Formula():
    function_name = ""
    variables = []
    expression = ""
    __expr__ = ""
    other_func_calls = 0
    def __init__(self, function_name:str, variables:list, fun:str) -> None:
        self.function_name = function_name
        self.variables = variables
        self.expression = fun
        other_func = []
        for i in fun:
            if ord(i) in range(ord("A"), ord("Z") + 1):
                self.other_func_calls += 1
                other_func.append(i)
        self.__expr__ = re.sub('[A-Z]?\((\w|, )*\)','_TBR_', fun) # _TBR_ is being replaced later 
        self.other_func = other_func # list of other functions in chronological order
 
class Pyramid():
    name:str
    functions:dict[str:Formula]
 
    def __init__(self, name:str, funs:dict[str:Formula]) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.functions = funs

    def get_result(self, fun:str, values:dict[str:int]):

        if (self.functions[fun].other_func_calls == 0): # Function does not call other functions 
            return eval(self.functions[fun].expression, values)

        other_funcs = copy.deepcopy(self.functions[fun].other_func)
        s = self.functions[fun].__expr__

        for i in range(len(other_funcs)):
            other_funcs[i] = self.get_result(other_funcs[i], values)
            s = re.sub("_TBR_", f"({str(other_funcs[i])})", s, count=1)
            
        return eval(s, values)
 

a = {
    "V": Formula("V", ["x", "y"], "G(y) * x / 3"),
    "U": Formula("U", ["x", "y"], "G(y)**2 / (9 * V(x, y)) + V(x, y)"),
    "G": Formula("G", ["y"], "1 - y")
}
 
p = Pyramid("Testing", a)
print(p.get_result("U", {"x":2,"y":3}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
>>> def Formula(*args):
...   return parse_expr('{%s(*%s): %s}' % args)
...
>>> f =[
...  Formula("G", ["y"], "1 - y"),
...  Formula("V", ["x", "y"], "G(y) * x / 3"),
...  Formula("U", ["x", "y"],"(G(y)**2) / (9 * V(x, y)) + V(x, y)")
... ]
>>> f
[{G(y): 1 - y}, {V(x, y): x*G(y)/3}, {U(x, y): G(y)**2/(9*V(x, y)) + V(x, y)}]
```

`f` is already topologically sorted so back substitute

```
>>> from sympy import Dict
>>> e=Dict(f[-1])
>>> e=e.subs(f[-2])
>>> e=e.subs(f[-3])
>>> a,b=dict(e).popitem()
>>> U = Lambda(a.args,b)
>>> U(2,3)
-5/3
```

If it's not sorted, you can use the `topological_sort`, perhaps via `repsort` [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6257#issuecomment-364794533) to do so:

```
>>> repsort(*[tuple(i.items()) for i in f])
[(U(x, y), G(y)**2/(9*V(x, y)) + V(x, y)), (V(x, y), x*G(y)/3), (G(y), 1 - y)]
>>> s = _
>>> expr = s[0][0]
>>> for i in s:
...   expr = expr.subs(*i)
...
>>> expr
x*(1 - y)/3 + (1 - y)/(3*x)
>>> U = Lambda(tuple(ordered(expr.free_symbols)), _)
>>> U(2,3)
-5/3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @smichr. The problem is that the `f` list is not alwats topologically sorted! So I decided to overcome my laziness and wrote my own parser that recursively calls each function, when needed. Anyways, I liked an Idea to use `parse_expr` and sympy's Dict in such way.

Comment: answer updated; also the Formula function could just as well return a tuple instead of a Dict -- the tuple-ized forms are used in the building of the `expr` in the second part of the answer.